# c# Why does the use of Process cause standard input to be hidden

Tags: c#, .net-core, console

I am writing a command line control program and need to read something from the console, But I found that when using Process to execute an program (git), the console input will be hidden (similar to password input)

Under windows, the program can run correctly, but under linux, the console input no longer displays any characters (the program can get the input value, it looks like a password input).

I reproduced a minimal example, the code is as follows, which can be obtained through [github](https://github.com/ymh199478/bug-report-1):

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var inputStream = Console.OpenStandardInput();
    Console.SetIn(new StreamReader(inputStream));

    ListReference();

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter something first:");
    var line = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine($"read first: {line}");

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter something second:");
    line = ReadInput(inputStream);
    Console.WriteLine($"read second: {line}");
}

private static void ListReference()
{
    var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process
    {
         StartInfo =
         {
            FileName = GetShellPath(),
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
         },
    };

    var command = "git show-ref --head -d";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = GetShellCommand(command);
    process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "repo");
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}

private static string GetShellPath()
{
    if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
    {
          return "cmd.exe";
    }

    if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux)
                || RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
    {
          return "/bin/bash";
    }

    throw new NotSupportedException("The operating system does not support executing the command line.");
}

private static string GetShellCommand(string command)
{
     if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows))
     {
           return $"/c \"{command}\"";
     }

     if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux)
          || RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX))
     {
           return $"-c \"{command}\"";
     }

     throw new NotSupportedException("The operating system does not support executing the command line.");
}

private static string ReadInput(Stream inputStream, Encoding encoding = null)
{
    string ret = null;
    encoding ??= Encoding.UTF8;

    // We only correct the position when we allow seek.
    long position = 0;
    if (inputStream.CanSeek)
    {
         position = inputStream.Position;
    }

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(inputStream, encoding,
                true, 128, true))
    {
          ret = reader.ReadLine();

          // We skip this step directly when it is not allowed,
          // because there will be no bugs even if you do not
          // use position correction under the console program.
          // It contains a potential problem: !5
          if (inputStream.CanSeek && !(ret is null))
          {
               inputStream.Seek(
                        position + encoding.GetByteCount(ret.ToString()) + encoding.GetByteCount(Environment.NewLine),
                        SeekOrigin.Begin);
          }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

When the function `ListReference` is annotated, it can run normally under Linux, but once the ListReference function is run, there will be abnormal input.

What causes the inconsistency of behavior under window and linux, what am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT：** I tried to exec the git program directly, but the problem still exists.

```cs
 var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process
 {
        StartInfo =
        {
            FileName = "git",
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
        },
};

process.StartInfo.Arguments = "show-ref --head -d";
```

Comment: My guess you just have to do `Console.OpenStandardInput` again.

Comment: @Sinatr I tried to re-open it, but it didn't work.

Comment: What is the value of `line`? In other words: is the problem with reading or outputting?

Comment: @Sinatr The value of line will be the value entered in the console，The program can get the input value correctly and output it correctly, but when the key is pressed, it will become like a password input (The entered characters are not displayed in the console, until after pressing Enter, the program can receive the input value)

Comment: This problem is caused by a Microsoft bug and will be fixed in 5.0：https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/43866